# Interstitial ad on emulator returns error in onAdFailedToLoad. "Code": 3, "Message": "No ad config."

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to show an interstitial ad on Emulator with my self created ad units but it returns error in onAdFailedToLoad. The complete error is:-

{
"Code": 3,
"Message": "No ad config.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null",
"Response Info": {
"Response ID": "null",
"Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
"Adapter Responses": [],
"Response Extras": {}
}
}

Can you please help me resolve this issue?

NOTE:- It works fine with the demo ad units provided by Google both on the emulator and phone device. It works fine with my self created ad units + phone device. Its not working in the case of self created ad units + Emulator

My MainActivity.java looks like following:-

```
package com.devdroid.adsample;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdView adView;
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        MobileAds.initialize(this);

        //List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("5C47592AA996CC9DE9BDB0A156ED2242");

        //RequestConfiguration configuration = new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        //        .setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();

        //MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        //if(adRequest.isTestDevice(this))
        //    Log.d("AddedAsTestDevice", "Successfully Done!");
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        InterstitialAd.load(this, getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                        Log.e("ErrorAdLoad", loadAdError.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        super.onAdLoaded(interstitialAd);

                        Log.d("SuccessAdLoad", "Ad loaded successfully");
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        //mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);

                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdClicked() {
                                super.onAdClicked();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                                super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdImpression() {
                                super.onAdImpression();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            //mHandler = new Handler();
            //mStatusChecker.run();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if  (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                        Log.d("AdShow", "Succeeded" );
                    }
                    else
                        Log.e("AdPending", "Ad is not ready yet!");
                }
            }, 10000);
    }
}
```

Strings.xml looks like following:-

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AdSample</string>
    <string name="app_id">ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~YYYYYYYYYY</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY</string>
    <string name="interstitial_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY</string>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AdSample"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```